# How can I change text color of items in safe area in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I am trying to change the color of text and other icons in `SafeAreaView` (check this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoa7E.png)) based on theme in react-native-ui-kitten. I tried setting color in stylesheet but no good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [Status bar's props `barStyle`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#barstyle) like this:

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
...
<StatusBar barStyle="light-content" /> //or "dark-content" 
...
```

[DOC example](https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `StatusBar` - a react native base component to change your item color.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#barstyle